# mysql sort group by total and name not working

Tags: mysql

I have Php program that outputs names with the corresponding events attended and the number of times each event was attended over a period of time. As an example of the output

```
Name | Run | Swim | Bike | Total

John    3     2      5      10
```

MySQL query look something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
            e.name as Leader,                                       
            SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 26 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Swim",
            SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 25 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Bike",
            SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 24 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Run",
            COUNT("Swim"+"Bike"+"Run") as total
        FROM 
            events as e   
        LEFT JOIN event_categories as c ON c.uid = e.uid
        WHERE 
            (DATE(e.event_start) BETWEEN "'.$from_date.'" and "'.$to_date.'") 
        GROUP BY Leader WITH ROLLUP;';
```

This works well, however, if I want to sort my data by "total" in descending order I get no output if I replace the last GROUP BY line with the following:

```
  GROUP BY total DESC, Leader WITH ROLLUP;';
```

so that I get a listing with names who have the highest totals to the lowest, and people with the same totals get listed in alphabetical order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `ORDER BY` and `ROLLUP` can not be used together. It states this here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) about half way down the page. To get around this, you'll have to do the ORDER BY in another query where your original query acts as the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            e.name as Leader,                                       
            SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 26 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Swim",
            SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 25 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Bike",
            SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 24 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Run",
            COUNT("Swim"+"Bike"+"Run") as total
        FROM 
            events as e   
        LEFT JOIN event_categories as c ON c.uid = e.uid
        WHERE 
            (DATE(e.event_start) BETWEEN "'.$from_date.'" and "'.$to_date.'") 
        GROUP BY Leader WITH ROLLUP     
    ) as rolldup
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

### ORIGINAL (WRONG) ANSWER:

You do not put Sorts in a `GROUP BY` clause. You put them in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
        e.name as Leader,                                       
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 26 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Swim",
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 25 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Bike",
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 24 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as "Run",
        COUNT("Swim"+"Bike"+"Run") as total
    FROM 
        events as e   
    LEFT JOIN event_categories as c ON c.uid = e.uid
    WHERE 
        (DATE(e.event_start) BETWEEN "'.$from_date.'" and "'.$to_date.'") 
    GROUP BY Leader WITH ROLLUP
    ORDER BY total DESC;';
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but get no results (i.e. I don't even get the GROUP BY Leader). Seems like it should work but doesn't.

Comment: GROUP BY can't take the number of results down to 0 and ORDER BY has no affect on the number of results, so there is something wrong with the rest of your query. Since you are using a LEFT JOIN either you have no records in your `events` table (very unlikely) or you have no events between your `$from_date` and your your `$to_date` (extremely likely).

Comment: Seems ROLLUP is the problem.  For some reason it cannot be used with an ORDER BY.  Is there another option to get the same totals?

Comment: Damn. Yep, I missed that. I just amended my answer to make use of a separate query to perform your order by. It should do the trick.

Comment: Works a charm.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to GROUP BY Total you just want to ORDER BY total.
So the two last lines of your query should be

```
 GROUP BY Leader WITH ROLLUP
 ORDER BY total DESC
```